# MobileServiceTableOperationError When Adding New Field

Tags: c#, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile Services project that is based off of the offline to do list example:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/

The example application with offline data is working as expected.  The problem is when I want to modify the ToDoItem with a new field.  If I modify the ToDoItem class with a new field (both the Windows app TodoItem class and the AzureMobileService app TodoItem class) with the following:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "NewData")]
public byte[] NewData { get; set; }
```

When I try to add a new item:

```
await MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync();
```

I get the error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServicePushFailedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Push operation has failed. See the PushResult for details.
```

The PushResult then has this error:

```
{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync.MobileServiceTableOperationError}
```

It is my understanding that the Azure Mobile Service supports Dynamic Schema, so I should not have to manually update the database.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

I am using a .NET backend.

**Update 1/31/2015**

If I modify the MobileServiceInitializer from:

```
public class MobileServiceInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MobileServiceContext>
```

to:

```
public class MobileServiceInitializer : ClearDatabaseSchemaIfModelChanges<MobileServiceContext>
```

It will correctly update the database, but of course clears all of my data in the table.  Any idea why DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges is throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because Azure Mobile Services doesn't have permission to Drop your database. See this blog here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/writingdata_services/archive/2014/03/28/mobile-services-net-backend-initializers-and-model-updates.aspx

The blog lays out two options, if this is your problem:

1. Drop existing tables - Which has all the problems you're talking about
2. Enable Code First Migration - which allows you to keep your data. Code First migration is a bit tricky, so be prepared for that, but it is one solution for your problem. The Blog above goes into this a bit but this is a more depth demo of doing a Migration in EF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/JJ591621.aspx

Comment: That was exactly the information I was looking for, thanks for the help!